# How can I left loin a table / entity with doctrine (Symfony)?

Tags: symfony, oop, doctrine, left-join, entity

in mySQL this is my table `pages`:

```
id  unique_id    name      template     icon    slug
1   jc62368231   Felder                  2     fields
```

and my table `icons`:

```
id  name
1   adjust
2   anchor
```

In my Controller.php I get the content from `Pages` via doctrine:

```
$pages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->findAll();
```

Here is my output:

```
   array:1 [▼
      0 => Pages {#4930 ▼
        -id: 5
        -unique_id: "jc62368231"
        -name: "Felder"
        -template: ""
        -icon: "2"
        -slug: "fields"
      }
    ]
```

What I want to do is join the table `icons` to the `pages` table. To achieve this result:

```
      array:1 [▼
      0 => Pages {#4930 ▼
        -id: 5
        -unique_id: "jc62368231"
        -name: "Felder"
        -template: ""
        -icon: "anchor"
        -slug: "fields"
      }
    ]
```

This is my approach:

```
$pages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->join();

 /**
  * @return Pages[]
  */

  public function join('icons')
  {
    ->leftJoin('icons.id', 'icon')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
    ;
  }
```

But I get this error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 60 near 'icon': Error: Class
>   App\Entity\Pages has no association named id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of your `join()` method is a non sense. You're calling method of an object without using an object.

The join isn't used that way. You have to use `entityAlias.memberName`

Try this approach, if you want to use it in your controller :

```
$pages = $this->getDoctrine()
              ->getRepository(Pages::class)
              ->createQueryBuilder('p') //Alias p for Page
              ->leftJoin('p.icon', 'i') //you are joining the icon member
              ->getQuery()
              ->getResult();
```

But I suggest you to use a [Repository class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository) instead :

In /src/Repository/PagesRepository.php :

```
class PagesRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function GetIcons()
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p') //Alias p for Page
                      ->leftJoin('p.icon', 'i') //you are joining the icon member
                      ->getQuery()
                      ->getResult();

        return (query);
    }
}
```

In your controller :

```
$pages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->GetIcons();
```

In your entity :

```
/*
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PagesRepository")
 */
class Pages
{
    //Your entity
}
```

An unique page has an unique icon.

An icon can have many pages.

From the page context, this is a **ManyToOne** relation (many pages can have one icon)

In your entity `Page`, the definition of the icon should be written that way :

```
/**
 * @var \Icons
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Icons")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="icon", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $icon;
```

For more informations, check the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional)

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I tested your code in the PagesRepository, but I get the error message: `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 50 near 'i': Error: Class App\Entity\Pages has no association named icon`

Comment: My class Name: `class PagesRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository`

Comment: does the `icon` entity not need to be defined somewhere?

Comment: Ah ok, this information was missing to me all the time. I just know join left from pdo. I did not know that the relation is made in the entity. This helps me very much. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome, keep in mind that when working with ORM, you don't think with tables, but with entities. Things will become clearer with time and practice :)

Comment: Yes, I should forget the tables, I am still so used to mySQL and pdo...

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? I updated my pages entity as you suggested. But I still get the error message `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 50 near 'i': Error: Class App\Entity\Pages has no association named icon`

Comment: I know now, what was the reason, I also used `@ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)`. I am not allowed to do that when I use `  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Icons")`

Comment: Yes, indeed, this is not a string, but an entity